# NodeJS: Detecting if a user would have read access to a file

Tags: node.js, unix, filesystems

In a NodeJS script run as **non-root** user1, how can I detect if a specified user2 has read access to a file on disk?

Note that root access is **not available** for this process, and user2's login credentials are not available, so something like `sudo -u user2 namei /path/to/file` is a no-go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I used (not NodeJS specific) to find if user1 has access to an existing file:

1. Is the file globally readable? If so, return `true`, else go to 2
2. Is the file group readable? If so, go to 3, else go to 4
3. Does user1's `group` contain the group ID of the file? If so, return `true`, else go to 4
4. Is the file user readable? If so, go to 5, else return `false`
5. Is the file owner `user1`? If so, return `true`, else return `false`

This checks all common access and group restrictions on files.

Answer (score 0):

Per the Node.js documentation, [fs.access()](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_access_path_mode_callback) can be used to determine access:

```
// Check if the file is readable.
fs.access(file, fs.constants.R_OK, (err) => {
  console.log(`${file} ${err ? 'is not readable' : 'is readable'}`);
});
```

Such that the presence of `err` indicates that the file is not readable.

Comment: How can user1 check if user2 can access a given file using fs.access?

Comment: That is truly my bad - apparently my brain saw, and then dropped, the notion of two separate users. Based on what I know from the documentation, and the behaviors of *nix operating systems, there's probably not a good, non-fragile way of doing this. The first user may not have access to the file in question to use `fs.stat` to get , and even with that, you would need to parse /etc/passwd and /etc/group _if_ the user is a local user to compute access.

Comment: I reckon the bigger question is, what are you trying to accomplish, and why does the Node.js application need to be the one to do it?

Comment: This is a good question. It does not have to be the Node.js application that performs this operation. I will open a separate question to see if a plain shell can do it via /etc/passwd and /etc/group parsing as you mentioned.